# How to get Pokéballs in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have used all my Pokéballs to catch Pokémon. Now I'm trying to get more Pokéballs, but don't know how. I can't see any gym or Pokéstop on my map either. Is there any way to earn Pokéballs or will I get them on a daily basis?

Comment: Are you living in a small village? Having no Pokéstop or gyms around is pretty rare.

Comment: no..at present m in office with my 3 friends  and all are facing the same issue.. and only getting ratta and spraow :(

Comment: Ok, as it seems you are in a country where the game isn't released, yet. You will probably have to wait for an updated map of your region. They might still work on filling the map with Pokéstops and gyms.

Comment: @dly yup i think i should wait..thank you for your time :)

Comment: Some one wants to close this question as off topic?? cmmon guyz...please comment before doing this. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps because this is an issue that you can't encounter unless you're playing in an unsupported region?  Seems like a pretty good reason to close to me.

Comment: Well then we should close all the question related to pokemon go as i can see plenty of question from unsupported region. And we are facing issue that's why we are here but not to support of pokemon go..Think before closing. You have power, doesn't mean you can do anything.

Comment: Not sure why people are closing this as off-topic.  Even if the game is unreleased in his region, it is released in others, so it is answerable and on-topic.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The title is a fine question. But given the detail it is effectively "given that the game isn't available for me, how do I play the game?" Which I can see as a good rationale for closing, if, for example, the asker was refusing to accept any answer that didn't solve the latter problem. Given that they didn't refuse to do that, question seems fine.

Comment: FYI - After you throw a pokeball, and it doesn't catch the pokemon, you can tap the pokeball to pick it back up, so it's not wasted.

Comment: Have you played Ingress? If you see a fair number of portals in your area in Ingress, but no equivalent Poke Stops, chances are Niantic hasn't migrated the data to PoGo for your region yet (since it's not officially released there). If you don't see portals in Ingress, then your area will be Poke-Stop-sparse :(

Comment: @deworde well i did not said that i will refuse to accept any answer. Please read my message that i will accept your answer if i won't get any better. And i have walked miles in my city and found pokestops and gym so it means Niantic is allowed them so its not off topic. Please try to help. Thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Next to **PokéStops** you will only receive Poké Balls, when you **Level Up** or when you use the **Shop**.

The Poké Ball's successors (Great Ball, Ultra Ball, ...) are currently not purchasable in the Shop yet. They can only be received with the two former cases.

Comment: No **pokestops** on my map..i tried travelling here to there but no luck. Even i mentioned this in my question :(

Comment: @LeothelionYes I noticed that, but just added it as well for the sake of completeness :)

Comment: If i will not get any other good answer then i will go with your answer as this helped me and will help others with same issue :) thank you

Comment: You could also try restarting your app, sometimes pokestops fail to load

Comment: @Pyritie i have restart app so many time but i think they have removed as yesterday night i can see but now there is nothing in map even i have drive my bike arround 3 to 4 km in lunch time..will check more in evening then will share.

Comment: @Leothelion What country are you located in?

Comment: I am in India..here pokemon go is not yet released. M using apk.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 thank you so much. I have visited my city and found so many pokestop(all are temples and historic place) and also got gym. I clicked on pokestops and got egg, pokeball and essent. Thank you so much for your time. :)

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know, most or all PokeStops and Gyms in Pokemon Go are taken from the game Ingress, which had few set Portals from Niantic and most Portals requested by Players. Which leaves a possibility that no one ever set or requested Portals at your location.


If you and your friends are certain, that there are no connectivity or GPS issues I second dly's comment:

> Until recently you were able to request Pokéstops, but apparently they took it down again. If you have no stops in your area at all it might still be a good idea to submit a ticket at [support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us](http://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us) – dly 3 mins ago

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment again as the OP said the game isn't released in their country, yet. Requesting a Pokéstop in an unfinished region is probably not a good idea.

Comment: The points of interest are called _portals_ in Ingress, not _events_. [Events in Ingress](https://www.ingress.com/events) are big meetups with lots of players. Portals were submitted (as in crowdsourced), not requested (as in "please put one in my street"), but that has been turned off for a while now because they could not handle their backlog.

Comment: @dly Why not? There's plenty of areas where the game isn't officially released yet which are mapped out already.

Comment: I wouldn't give support for a region that's not yet released. And I believe Niantic has enough to do with the regions that are already released.

Answer (score 3):

You can either retrieve them from PokeStops, get them while leveling up, or purchase them from the Pokemon Go store.

Comment: sorry but GO is not official launch in my country so i can't buy them.

Comment: you can buy them, it's not an issue at all if the game is not yet released in your country. At least, this is the case on my android phone using a credit card.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter well sorry but i will say you should not use your credit card in apk as they are not official and if you will lost your money then there will be no return so please be careful while using your card.